# Using V-For to provide values to Radio Button input?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Apologies if this is a super basic question, but I'm building a Radio Button component, which iterates over Array of Objects, each representing a User.

All the documentation and examples I see have hardcoded values, whereas my Array has constantly changing Users, what I want to know is, how I would adapt the below code to take the name of the Users as a value for each radio button.

```html
<input type="radio" id="one" value="One" v-model="picked">
<br>
<input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="picked">
<br>
<input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="picked">
<br>
<span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'UserRadioButton'
  data() {
    return {
      picked: 'name',
      Users: [{name:"Mary"},{name:"John"},{name:"Hank"}]
    };
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Render the list of `Users` with [`v-for`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for).
2. [Bind](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings) the `<input>.value` to each item's `name` in the `v-for`. This sets the radio's intended value when selected, and that's reflected in the `v-model`.

```html
<label v-for="user in Users" 1️⃣ >
  <input type="radio" v-model="picked" :value="user.name" 2️⃣ />
  <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
</label>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-radio-button-vmodel?file=src/components/UserRadioButton.vue)